# Can I use LinkingObjects for a One to Many relationship without List<> in Realm Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I currently have an app that uses a One-to-Many relationship as follow...

```
class Person: Object {
    @objc dynamic var personName = ""
    @objc dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
    let dogs = List<Dog>()
}

class Dog:Object{
    @objc dynamic var dogName:String = ""
    @objc dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
}
```

Everything works fine but I'm trying to use a `CloudKit` syncing framework that doesn't support the `List<SomeObject>` structure and the only option available is `LinkingObjects` so I would need to restructure my code as follow...

```
class Person: Object {
    @objc dynamic var personName = ""
    @objc dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
    let dogs = LinkingObjects(fromType: Dog.self, property: "owner")
}

class Dog:Object{
    @objc dynamic var dogName:String = ""
    @objc dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()
    @objc dynamic var owner: Person?
}
```

Is this a viable approach to accomplish a One-to-Many relationship in `Realm`?

Are there any issues if I use `LinkingObjects` as shown above to represent a One-to-Many relationship?

Thanks!

Comment: A List object is a one to many relationship. In your code, *one* person has *many* dogs. If you need to transverse back to the person *from* the dog, just add a Person property to the dog class `@objc dynamic var my_person: Person!` LinkingObjects is really most useful for many to many relationships - hence the name LinkingObject(s). It also provided 'auto' links back to the parent objects e.g. when an object with a LinkingObjects property is added to a list, it automatically creates that inverse relationship. Which may or may not be what you want, as it's many-many focused

Comment: What I need is a One-to-Many relationship but again, I'm using a framework (IceCream, CloudKit/Realm sync) that doesn't support the `List` object only the `LinkingObjects` structure. The `Dog` class already has a `Person` property.

Comment: Are you sure CloudKit supports *LinkingObjects* as that's a specific Realm ObjC object designed for inverse relationships. It's not a structure at all, but a class. If the Dog class has a owner/person property... what else do you need - maybe an array or do you need it managed by Realm... or CloudKit?? Perhaps you can update the question with more information as to what you're attempting to do - are you trying to store Realm objects in another type of database?

Comment: `CloudKit` doesn't' support `LinkingObjects` by default, the framework (IceCream) takes care of it, it works fine. My question is simply if `LinkingObjects` could be used for `One-to-Many` relationships without running into issues.  I have been playing around and it looks like it can be accomplished, in fact I can use the same queries I was using with the `List` object. Sorry, when I said structure I meant 'structure' in terms of code arrangement, not Swift `struct`.

Comment: Gotcha. LinkingObjects are designed to be a path back to a parent object so they do not have any kind of .add or .append function so with the code in your question for example, if you have a person object you can't say `person.dogs.append(aDog)`. Additionally LinkedObjects are not persisted in the same way as other objects are - e.g. they won't show up in Realm Studio as a property. Last thing is they won't be querable as a List is. You're have to use ANY e.g. `.filter("ANY tdogs.dog_name == 'Fido'"). That could lead to unexpected results.

Comment: So it's really not recommended for `One-to-Many` relationships?

Comment: It's not an object to build forward paths with. It's strictly for inverse relationships. As with many things, it can probably work in some other capacity but your results will probably not be consistent or provide what you want.

Comment: Thank your advice.